# Asp.net Core. Configure IOptions method with Type params (not generic)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, app-config, asp.net-core-configuration

Is there a way to call the method `Configure` from `IServiceCollection` `DI` container with non generic params?

I want to register my config section not like the following:

```
services.Configure<AppSection>(Configuration);
```

But in this way:

```
services.Configure(typeof(AppSection), Configuration);
```

I want to do this as I want to pass my config sections by `List<Type>` collection from low-level application levels(`DAL`) to High-level (`Web api`). And then make only a loop by this collection with registration each section.

```
foreach (var type in LowAppLevelSections)
{
   services.Configure(type, Configuration);
}
```

So, in the end I will not have strong dependency between for example `DAL` and `Web API` level.

Is there any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an approach. All you have to do is clean it up a bit, write some unit tests. (Again sorry for the messy code)

```
public static class IServicesCollectionExtension
{
    public static IServiceCollection Configure(this IServiceCollection services, Type typeToRegister, IConfiguration service)
    {
        var myMethod = typeof(OptionsConfigurationServiceCollectionExtensions)
          .GetMethods(BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public)
          .Where(x => x.Name == nameof(OptionsConfigurationServiceCollectionExtensions.Configure) && x.IsGenericMethodDefinition)
          .Where(x => x.GetGenericArguments().Length == 1)
          .Where(x => x.GetParameters().Length == 2)
          .Single();

        MethodInfo generic = myMethod.MakeGenericMethod(typeToRegister);
        generic.Invoke(null, new object[] { services, service });
        return services;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks :) I know about this way, I hoped there is some way without reflection.